# Wordpress backend on AWS ElasticBeanstalk doesn't work?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services

My team and I are working on migrating our Wordpress website to AWS, but we're having some troubles in the final stretch.  We've got the database, code, uploads, etc. all hosted in AWS RDS and ElasticBeanstalk, with a Route53 A-type record alias pointing from the desired address to our Beanstalk instance.  When we hit the URL, it properly redirects to the Beanstalk, and we can see our website as intended.  The problem arises when we try to access the backend:

[image: WP Backend with no styling]

The backend has no styling, and when I try to log in it gives me a 404 error, having redirected me to `website.com/website.com/wp-admin/` (it's appending the entire url to the end of the domain instead of just the `wp-admin/` extension).  Oddly enough, when I change the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` variables in the `wp-config.php` to `http://website.com` instead of just `website.com`, the Wordpress login looks as it should, but only for about 30 seconds, and then I get "This page isn’t working. 
 website.com took too long to respond."

Here is the .htaccess file I'm using (the basic .htaccess from the Wordpress Codex):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any insights as to what might be going on would be greatly appreciated, as we've been wrestling with this for a few days now.  I'm also happy to provide any additional information as necessary.  Thanks!

UPDATE:
When I log into Wordpress through the screen in the picture (without http:// in the config) with devtools open I get the following:

wp-login.php

```
Request URL: http://www.website.com/wp-login.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 123.456.789.101:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

wp-admin/

```
Request URL: http://www.website.com/www.website.com/wp-admin/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 123.456.789.101:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Comment: When you debug with your browser does the network tab show that its redirecting the /wp-admin/ via 301 redirect?

Comment: @danwebb I've updated my question with the information you requested.  It looks like I'm getting a 302

Comment: Because youre redirecting to website.com/website.com/wp-admin/ I suspect the site URL is incorrect in the options table

Comment: When I set `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in the `wp-config.php`, doesn't that override what's in the database?

Comment: It should but sometimes you have to add define('RELOCATE', true); for it to work when change environments/servers. IDK if you have already tried that but I would try to see if that works.